# Add paypal payment method to an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, paypal

I would like to add paypal payment method to my app like in uber app. I want that the user log in once in the browser and from then on the app should book the money by sliding a button without needing to log in again or go to paypal website/app.
I have checked everything and i just found the paypal sdk to add paypal button which navigat to paypal log in screen.
I appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing in your requirements is being able to bill a PayPal account later without a login. The integration platform/environment (Android) will also be important, but of secondary concern.

In PayPal this functionality used to be known as "Reference Transactions with Billing Agreements", on Mobile it was for a time called "Future Payments", and in very new integrations it's called Vault (v2 REST API vault, not the old v1/vault which is of no use).  It can also be done with PayPal's separate Braintree service if you are approved for that gateway.

Any of the above functionality is only available if PayPal turns in on for your production account, so you need to contact PayPal about it, specifically the *business* side of PayPal via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us or a sales department (not the MTS technical support, which doesn't enable any production account features)

If reference transactions *does* get enabled and approved for your live/production business account (no guarantee of this), then PayPal will guide you on which specific API to use, which could be the newest v2 Vault, or something else.